# ubuntustudio-controls how to output sound to 4 speaker at the same time?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

My focusrite 4i4 has 4 outputs, i have two set of monitors.

How can i output my sound to the four at the same time ?
(i managed to make it 1,2 or 3,4 but not 1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why we have "Open Carla" as a shortcut within Ubuntu Studio Controls.

Open Carla, go to the Patchbay tab, and simply drag lines from your PulseAudio output (labeled "pulse_out" by default) to your Focusrite 4i4 outputs (if set to master, labeled "system"):

[image]

This is using my system, which isn't the same hardware, but you should get the idea.

Comment: i feel stupid now ... thank you , loving the simplificy of studio-control