# Ubuntu Studio Controls: How to add and map surround audio channels to a pulse output bridge?

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, ubuntu-studio, jack

I am using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 with JACK through `ubuntustudio-controls`. I have a surround speaker system and must change the default `pulse_out` bridge sink from **2-channel** stereo to **4-channel**. The four channels must be mapped to `front-left` `front-right` `rear-left` `rear-right`. This does not seem to be an option through the GUI.

Alternatively, I can add an additional 2-channel Output bridge, but the channels would still need to be mapped to the rear speakers. There doesn't seem to be any way of doing that either.

Making a single 4-channel output bridge would be preferable.

This could normally be manually configured through `pacmd load-module module-jack-sink sink_name=Surround client_name=Surround channels=4 connect=no` but **Ubuntu Studio Controls** wipes out any manual changes once "**Start or Restart Jack**" is clicked. If no solution is available, it seems avoiding Ubuntu Studio Controls would be the only option. Sadface.

I can imagine this would be an important feature since many professional musicians, studio engineers and audiophiles have 5.1 and 7.1 surround speaker systems, but the [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioControls) has no information on the subject.

How can I configure the number of channels in an Output Bridge through Ubuntu Studio Controls?

Comment: You have to use Carla, check this answer :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239448/ubuntustudio-controls-how-to-output-sound-to-4-speaker-at-the-same-time

Comment: Doing what that thread suggests would duplicate front-left and front-right channels instead of mapping 4 or more channels.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to a Ubuntu Studio developer and discovered this feature is not yet in Ubuntu Studio Controls. They made a note to add it for a future release.